# <utility> not necessarily included when swap() is performed - How can this become a problem?

Tags: c++, stl, header-files

Reading [C++ named requirements: Swappable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Swappable) I've come across the following note

> It is unspecified whether `<utility>` is actually included when the standard library functions perform the swap, so the user-provided swap() should not expect it to be included.

Suppose I have a user-defined type `class Foo` with a user-provided `swap()`. I'd like to use a Standard Library algorithm for my `class Foo` that performs a swap with

```cpp
using std::swap;
swap(arg1, arg2);
```

as described in the above-mentioned cppreference article, and the file that I have to
`#include` to use this algorithm does NOT `#include <utility>`.

If I relied on functionality provided by `<utility>` in my `swap()`, how could this lead to a problem? I'd have to `#include <utility>` myself in the file that defines my `swap()`. The scenario should be similar to the following: I have a file that `#includes` my `class Foo` with my user-provided `swap()` and the header for the algorithm that I use. Consequently, there should never be an issue regarding whether the algorithm does `#include <utility>` or not.

I might have misunderstandings revolving around how `#include` and compilation could interact with each other in some different scenarios. Which situation could potentially lead to compilation issues here?

Comment: Looking at [gcc implementation](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/std/algorithm.html) of `<algorithm>`, it does seem to include `<utility>` but with a comment 'UK-300'. Hoping somebody will clarify what it means.

Comment: @Tharsalys For instance, in libstdc++, `std::partition` algorithm uses `std::iter_swap` internally, which is defined [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h#L182) in `bits/stl_algobase.h`. This header does not include `<utility>` nor any other involved header does as far as I can tell. I just includes `<bits/move.h> // For std::swap`, see [this line](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h#L70). It seems to be a case where `<utility> is not included` by an algorithm that uses swapping.

Comment: @DanielLangr I think we can conclude it's up to the implementation to "directly" include `<utility>` or not. So is there any case in which we run into the scenario described in the question?

Comment: @Daniel @Tharsalys According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) `<algorithm>` also defines `std::swap`. So the note might be about functionality provided by `<utility>` in particular?

Comment: @Ruperrrt `std::swap` was moved from `<algorithm>` to `<utility>` in C++11. cppreference has an "until C++11" and "from C++11" that are easy to miss

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try to understand the note you quoted from cppreference.

> It is unspecified whether `<utility>` is actually included when the standard library functions perform the swap, so the user-provided swap() should not expect it to be included.

E.g., `std::sort` may perform the swap. To use `std::sort`, you need to include `<algorithm>`. The statement basically says, despite this, `<algorithm>` may not have `<utility>` included. It follows that below code may be problematic.

```
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  int arr[] = { 4, 1, 7 };
  std::sort(arr, arr + 3);
  std::swap(arr[0], arr[1]); // may error out here
}
```

This is counter-intuitive, for `std::sort` performs `std::swap` internally itself. **To stay on the safe side, always explicitly include `<utility>` if you need `std::swap`. Don't assume that some other standard library headers that use `std::swap` themselves have `<utility>` included for you.** Following code should always work, while `#include <utility>` seems unnecessary at first sight.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

int main() {
  int arr[] = { 4, 1, 7 };
  std::sort(arr, arr + 3);
  std::swap(arr[0], arr[1]);
}
```

Comment: Spot on. Although using `std::swap` almost certainly *will* be safe at that point, even if `<utility>` isn’t included, because `std::sort` needs to have it defined in order to use it. A more realistic failure case would be to use any *other* function defined in `<utility>`, e.g. `std::exchange`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph an implementation is free to define `swap` in some other namespace than `std`, so long as `<utility>` `using`s it into `std`. This is separate to `<algorithm>` ensuring it is in the overload set that `sort` uses

Answer (score 1):

The short answer would be that the without explicit `#include <utility>`, there is no guarantee of `std::swap` fallback in case there is no custom `swap` for `Foo`s; leading to compilation errors.

If there is `using std::swap;` statement  somewhere in the code - yours, or inside the algorithm - then the `std::swap` function must already be included, otherwise you get a compilation error.

What the cppreference points at is that there is no guarantee that `std::foo_algorithm` will include `<utility>` and use `using std::swap;` construct before it calls `swap(a,b)`. Note that it uses unqualified name for the swap as it should.

This means that if your class depends on presence of `std::swap`, because it lacks any custom `swap` function, then calling `std::foo_algorithm` might result in compilation errors saying there is no appropriate `swap(Foo&,Foo&)` function, due to `std::swap` not being automatically included. The easy fix is to place `#include <utility>` before `#include <foo_algorithm>`.

But, if you have a custom swap and the algorithm can find it (either because it has been either included directly in the current namespace or ADL kicks in), everything will compile just fine. Unrelated to that, your swap should be using the `using std::swap; swap(a,b);` construct anyway, so `std::swap` is likely always present if your `swap` is.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The linked article states: "[...]  which means that any time the standard library performs a swap, it uses the equivalent of `using std::swap; swap(t, u);`" In conclusion, every file that defines Standard Library algorithms should _at least_ forward declare `std::swap`. Maybe this is what the note is about (`std::swap` potentially only being forward declared in the algorithm file)?

Comment: "calling std::foo_algorithm might result in compilation errors saying there is no appropriate swap(Foo&,Foo&) function" This is incorrect. What it is saying is that even though `<algorithm>` is required to have `std::swap` participate in name lookup, `std::swap(Foo&,Foo&)` might not be defined.